# Assign by value vs assign by reference PHP clarification on functions

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and still have to get a grasp on the & operator:

In the code below I still cannot understand why during the call to f2 the value does not get changed even though the f1 was declared with the & sign and when it gets called within the f2 does not change the value of the key "a".

```
<?php

function f1(&$array_param) {
  $array_param["a"] = "changed";
}

function f2($array_param) {
  f1($array_param);
}

$arr1 = ["a" => "Tadpole"];
$arr2 = ["a" => "Lily"];

$run1 = f1($arr1);
$run2 = f2($arr2);

echo $arr1["a"] . " " . $arr2["a"];
```

Does this mean that the & operator can be used when declaring a function but when we then invoke the same function we can omit it or decide whether we want to invoke that same function by passing the parameter by value or reference ? Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: You discard returned value of `$run2 = f2()` and instead use non-referenced `$arr2`

Comment: In case of `f2`, the value isn't changed because the call to `f2` breaks the connection. Since `f2` doesn't accept the array by reference, it receives a *copy* of the value. Changing that copy isn't visible outside `f2`.

Comment: @Justinas The return value of both functions is `null` anyway.

Comment: @deceze Oh, yes. `f1` missing return statement

Comment: @deceze What you are saying is that basically even though f1 is called within f2 that value passed does not get changed as f2 receives only a copy of the argument as there is no & operator ?

Comment: Yes. If you checked `$array_param` *inside* `f2`, you'd see that it changed. But since `$array_param` is already a copy of `$arr2`, that change doesn't reflect on `$arr2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call by reference is used in f1 only. We are calling f2 by value not by reference. So that value of array is changed only within f2 (which is calling f1).

```
<?php

function f1(&$array_param) {
    $array_param["a"] = "changed";
}

function f2($array_param) {
    echo "Before: " . $array_param["a"];  // Will return Lily
    f1($array_param);                     // Passing by reference
    echo "After: " . $array_param["a"];  // Will return changed
}

$arr1 = ["a" => "Tadpole"];
$arr2 = ["a" => "Lily"];

$run1 = f1($arr1);
$run2 = f2($arr2); // Here we are passing by value so got only Lily

echo $arr1["a"] . " " . $arr2["a"];
```